# Inheritance from python class generated with boost::python

Tags: python, boost-python

I'm having a problem with inheriting from a python class that I generated using boost::python.

I have a class whose function Print() is defined like this:

```
void CMagnet::Print()
{
  cout << "Hello" << endl;
}
```

and the interface is defined like this in my .cpp file:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE (CMagnet)
{
   class_<CMagnet>("CMagnet")
      .def("Print", &CMagnet::Print)
      ;
}
```

In principle, the module works, but I run into problems with inheritance. Here's an example:

```
from CMagnet import CMagnet

class DerMagnet(CMagnet):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Print()

a = CMagnet()
a.Print()

b = DerMagnet()
```

What I get is:

hirbel> python der_test.py

```
Hello

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "der_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    b = DerMagnet()
  File "der_test.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.Print()
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    CMagnet.Print(DerMagnet)
did not match C++ signature:
    Print(CMagnet {lvalue})
```

Meaning that when I instantiate the CMagnet class, I can call the Print() method without problems, but when I inherit from it and the derived class tries to call the method, the self argument is automatically inserted as the first argument and the signature is wrong. How would I resolve this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: you didn't call `CMagnet.__init__` from `DerMagnet`'s - `CMagnet.__init__(self)`

Answer (score 1):

I confirm @kerim comment.

If you don't call parent class "__init__" method, you got this kind of error message.